# Send Data and File image to the Back end

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have a problem to sent Data and Image from my Angular UI to the Spring Boot Backend.

My HTML:

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileSelected($event)">

<button type="button" (click)="onUpload()" class="file-input">sdadsa</button>
```

My component:

```
 selectedFile:File = null;


     onFileSelected(event) {
    this.selectedFile = <File>event.target.files[0];
  }

  onUpload() {
    const fb = new FormData();
    const data = new CategoryModel("s", "s", "s", 1);

    fb.append('image', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    this.data.storeProduct(data, fb).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    })

  }
```

My service:

```
/** POST Product on server */
  storeProduct(category: CategoryModel, fd: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.cateogryUrl, { category, fd }).pipe(

      catchError(this.handleError<CategoryModel>('addHero'))

    )
  }
```

And finally my Spring Boot method:

```
@PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void create(@RequestBody CategoryModel bike, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {


        String fileName = fileStorageService.storeFile(file);
        bike.setImagePath(fileName);
        categoryRepository.save(bike);
    }
```

When I send data I have this error:

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
```

Comment: did you use nodejs in backend ?

Comment: I using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Add `'enctype': 'multipart/form-data'` into your http request header.

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data' );

// HTTP POST using these headers
this.http.post(url, data, {headers: headers});
```

Comment: I add this, and this not helped.
`const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' })
};
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataServiceService `

Comment: Are you using intercepter for adding request header?